# Sending redirect without needed attributes

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

In method I have only `HttpServletRequest` attribute, but it isn't enough for redirect I think. Is it possible to send redirect to another page with this? Maybe there are ways to get the HttpServletResponse by this one? How? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> @Context
>   HttpServletResponse response;

to get the servlet response. After forward the request in a url/inner page

Comment: But I can't use more attributes than I have now. Or maybe with `@Context` I dont have to pass this one into the method?

Comment: You can always set new attributes to a Servlet request. You can do that by adding a parameter to request or session. Use session.setAttribute(atributemame, atributevalue);

Comment: Please post some code and tell me what are you trying to accomplish

Comment: I have method like 
`private void myMethod(HttpServletRequest request){
if(condition){
//here i need to send redirect to another page
}}`
I can't pass any other attributes in this method, I can work only with request. Method can be only void type so I can't just `return "redirect:..."`. But I need to do it some another way.

Comment: Why would you redirect the request, if there is a specific reason use : response.sendRedirect("someurl");  . if not forward the request by using :RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("somejsp or someservlet");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
in this way all your request parameters will not be lost

Comment: I say what I dont have a response and have no possibility to add this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In spring MVC there is  ModelAndView object by using which you can redirect to another page code is given below .In set view write page name

```
    public ModelAndView submitlogin( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("index");
    return modelAndView;
}
```